# Using hg-git, TortoiseHg and github over https gives 401

Tags: git, github, mercurial, tortoisehg, hg-git

I'm using hg-git with TortoiseHg to try to push my existing repository to GitHub. I'm authenticating with HTTPS, rather than SSH. I added my username and password to TortoiseHg just like for BitBucket.

But TortoiseHg says that the remove server gives 401.

All the examples I could find for authenticating with hg-git use SSH rather than HTTPS.

How can I convince TortoiseHg to cough up my username and password to GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that a different combination of Google keywords reveals that this is a bug in some library which was fixed a few months ago so updating TortoiseHg solved the problem.

Comment: what version worked for you? with v3.1.2 (x64) I'm getting 404 not found errors. What magic keywords led you to the answer?